# Jersey 2 - JAXB

Tags: jaxb, jersey, tomcat7, jax-rs

Using Jersey 2 m13-3 in Tomcat 7, I'm trying to post XML and have JAXB automatically unmarshal it.

My method signature is something like:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces( {"text/xml"})
public Response setFoo(
        myXJC.generatedclass.Foo foo
        )
```

I get a 400 bad request, but no exception (that I can find).

Testing with:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces( {"text/xml"})
public Response setFoo() { ... }
```

I'm confident this method is being invoked in response to a request.

But as soon as I add arg myXJC.generatedclass.Foo, it isn't.

Do I need something special in my class which extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application to use JAXB? Something ResourceConfig related perhaps?  Any extra jersey specific jars?

I see there is a jersey-media-moxy.  I'd be happy to get it working with MOXy, but ideally it would also work with Sun/Oracle JAXB.

I've had a look at the source code of:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-m13-3</version>
</dependency>
```

but I'm still having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that when I generated the classes from my XSD using XJC, I'd left an incorrect target namespace in there.

The XML I was posting was not namespace qualified, but the generated classes were expecting a namespace.

Once I fixed this, things worked fine.